# Visual Studio 2012 Unit Test Report

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I need to create some report of the execution of my unit test cases (quantity of tests passed, failed and ignored). I looked around the internet but I didn't find any way to generate this. Does someone knows a simple (or complex) way to generate a unit test report locally? (I said locally because I have found a solution using the test manager but is not feasible to me righ now).

Comment: This link describes how to save and export test results if you are using MS TEST. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182499%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Another possible solution is to use NUnit. The GUI has a feature where you can export the test results as an XML file. http://www.nunit.org/

Comment: That link from @JonKittell no longer applies to VS2012. But you can run from the commandline with the option to use the `logger:trx` this should output a Test result File which you can export from Visual Studio. See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no option from the Visual Studio UI, but this can be accomplished from the command line. navigate to your solution directory and run the following command from the Visual Studio 2013 command line:

> vstest.console.exe /logger:trx .\TestProject\bin\debug\YourUnitTestAssembly.dll

This will create a TestResults folder under your solution root and drop a .trx file. By opening that file into Visual Studio you should see something like this:

[image]

The .trx file is easy to parse XML and can be converted into human readable data [using an XSLT, as explained in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878678/736079).

Normally Visual Studio creates this file during the run, but deletes it afterwards. It looks like my instance of Visual Studio will actually create such a trx file and keep it in a `$(solutionroot)\TestResults\{GUID}` directory when I use the Analyze code coverage feature:

[image]

[image]

To see if your version of Visual studio has the `Trx` logger installed, run the following command from a Visual Studio command prompt:

[image]

Comment: Is possible to use that command on VS 2012 too? I'm asking that because in my job I don't have the VS 2013 licence. Is this possible to use on VS 2013 express?

Comment: `vstest.console.exe` is available for VS2012 and VS2013 express as well. And the Test Window trick works in Visual studio 2012 as well, as long as you have an edition that can calculate code coverage (Premium or Ultimate) https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx

Comment: It works!! I going to explore more functionalities of the vtest.console. Now I can filtering by the namespace and now trying to change the name of the trx file. Tnks for the help!

Comment: So there's no way to have the TRX file logged programmatically? Using VS2015 but it looks like it's the same behavior.

Comment: How can I export .trx file with vstest.console when I have many test projects (let's say 20 test projects)?